# Does $\mathrm{GL}_{n-2}(\mathbb{Z})$ has an element of order $m$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let me introduce the context:
A few week ago I have made the following contest as a "homework" : [ENS contest (France) 2006](http://www.sujets-de-concours.net/sujets/ens/2006/mp/maths1.pdf) which is essentially about $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ group, finite subgroup of $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and as a final question : Any surjective morphism group $SL_n(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow SL_n (\mathbb{Z})$ is bijective.

Yesterday I had proved that $S_n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_{n-1}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Which is mainly a consequence of the mentioned contest.

So, here is my question :

> Assuming that [$S_n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group)  has an element of order $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Does the following group  $\mathrm{GL}_{n-2}(\mathbb{Z})$ has an element of order $m$ ?

For $n=\{1,2,3\}$ one can check the answers is no.

Unfortunately, I had no idea to disprove (perhaps the result is true for $n \geq 4$) the claim for higher values of $n$.

EDIT: It seems to be true for $n\ge 4$ and even. (Look at Greg's Martin answer).

Comment: It would be easier to parse your question if you included the definitions of $\mathfrak{S}_n$ and $m$.

Comment: @GregMartin You are right, I edited. Thanks

Comment: It seems to be true for $n\ge 2$ iff $n$ is not prime.

Comment: @YvesCornulier Interesting, do you have a solution ?

Comment: It's an exercise, it would be better to find it than reading a solution. Hint: do separately the case of a prime, a proper power of a prime, and the case of an integer with at least two prime factors.

Comment: @YvesCornulier I will try. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

One should be able to enumerate all possible finite orders of elements of GL$_k(\Bbb Z)$. The characteristic polynomial would have to be a product of cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_{q_i}$, and the order of the matrix would be the lcm of the $q_i$. Since the degree of the characteristic polynomial is (bounded by) $k$, this yields a finite list of possible orders. For $k=2$, the possible orders are $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$, so I think the answer is yes for $n=4$. But the answer is no for $n=5$, since no $3\times3$ matrix can have order $5$. (Indeed, the answer is no for any prime $n$.)

Comment: Ingenious, Thanks! It seems to be about even values for $n$.